# NSUserDefaults performance comparison

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a difference in speed between the following two cases:

**A:**

```
userName=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userName"];
userEmail=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userEmail"];
userId=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userId"] intValue];
```

**B:**

```
userDictionary=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userDictionary"];
userName=[userDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
userEmail=...etc...
```

Even though differences in speed might be extremely small, *technically*, are there performance differences?

Comment: What did your performance tests indicate? (The answer, btw, is usually yes, but there's no such requirement. The compiler could legally optimize it if it chose to. Only tests will tell you the difference.)

Comment: How do I run performance tests? (Also, I wanted to know the "why" rather than just a yes or no, which I can't answer)

Comment: By putting in a loop and running it a million times or so and timing it. As for "why," the first requests a method be called many times, which is more expensive than not calling that method. The compiler is allowed to optimize that. Clang can't really optimize it because it doesn't know that you haven't replaced `standardUserDefaults` with a method with side effects at runtime. So in practice it can't really be optimized and you have to make the calls. But this is usually the wrong approach to performance questions. Always start with tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C is fastest.

**C:**

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
userName=[defaults objectForKey:@"userName"];
userEmail=[defaults objectForKey:@"userEmail"];
userId=[[defaults objectForKey:@"userId"] intValue];
```

No sense calling the same method over and over, when you can cache the result locally and reuse it.  A method invocation is always going to be slower than accessing a local variable.

Comment: Though *likely* faster, it's not guaranteed. `-[NSUserDefaults objectForKey:]` might have different (worse) performance characteristics than `-[NSDictionary objectForKey:]`.

Comment: Oh wait so [defaults objectForKey.."] is not the same as [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]? Didn't know that..

Comment: @mohabitar `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` returns an instance of the class `NSUserDefaults`.  This fact allows you to cache the result to local variable, and accessing that local variabale will _always_ be faster than calling a method to get the same value.

Answer (score 1):

*Technically*, yes. But it would be rather unwise to speculate on which one is faster. A first-pass guess might be that **A** is faster, because it only does three lookups in a hash table, rather than four. But perhaps `+[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` uses a lock to make itself thread-safe, and perhaps that overhead is enough to make **B** faster. As a bonus, one might be faster this for one version of iOS while the other might be faster for another.

The difference is unpredictable and incredibly negligible. Use whichever makes the code simpler.

Comment: from an algorithmic and grand scope, this is a really terrible answer.